# Rake in Rails: should I be using db:reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm a little confused by  the intended use of the default Rails Rake tasks, and would like advice on whether I should be using `db:reset` or writing a custom Rake task. Nothing clever, just daily housekeeping, and I may well be missing an obvious doc as I'm new to Rails.

**My problem:** I want to throw away my database and run from a completely clean setup, in order that I can be sure the database contains known data only. This is useful for demo prep, for debugging, and for making sure Jenkins is comparing like-with-like in tests.

Currently, I'm writing this:

```
bin/rake db:drop:all db:create:all db:migrate db:seed db:test:prepare
```

This is a lot to type, but leaves seed data only in both dev and test databases. I am unsure how this differs from `db:reset`, which would be more convenient to type.

Should I use `db:reset` or write a custom `db:from_scratch` task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're not sure what a rake task does, then I would suggest not using it. In this case, you're probably ok, however `db:reset` is not the equivalent to what you are doing above. `db:reset` recreates the database from scheme.rb, this may be different as you could have written migrations that have not yet been run.

I would suggest that you use a custom rake task, you can then modify it to fit your exact purposes, especially if you want to perform other tasks as well (for example tagging in git)

Comment: Slightly clearer explanation, thanks. Confirms me in writing a custom task.

Answer (score 21):

You should be using:

```
rake db:reset
```

This will **drop** the database, **recreate** it and **load** the current schema into it.

For a full list of rake db tasks:

```
rake --describe db
```

If your requirements change then it would be better to write a custom rake task, where you can apply your own customisation.

Comment: So specifically reset doesn't address my issue of the test db being the same as the (blank) dev database, and containing the seed data. Custom sounds clearer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve in your the tasks you are running through rake is setting both the test and the development databases. `rake db:reset` will just do it for your current environment db according to the schema.rb and then load the seeds data into the db. The schema.rb in general is never edited, its for a know-only/refer-only purpose, however some people do tend have different schema.rb which might create a problem :(. What sounds better to me  is if you need to set both your development and test database, then run your migrations for the dev environment and use the schema.rb to create the test environment db. I would definitely suggest you to get a second opinion from some Rails guru though to find out a real perfect way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

rake db:reset
This will drop the database, recreate it and load the current schema into it.

rake db:reset will run rake db:seed

Example :

if you have seed file that you wrote after you ran your migration , it will run that too.